Tightness + marginal weak convergence implies joint weak convergence?
I remember learning something like
"If a random vector $Z_n=(Z_n^1, Z_n^2,\ldots, Z_n^d)$ is tight and each component of it $Z_n^i$ converges in distribution to $Z_i$ for all $i=1,\ldots,d$, then $Z_n$ jointly converges in distribution to $Z=(Z^1,Z^2,\ldots,Z^d)$."
but can't find any reference now. Is the statement correct?

Tightness is equivalent to an existance of a convergent subsequence.

It is not correct.
Take $X$ a standard gaussian variable. Set $Z_n=(X,X,X,\cdots,X)$ if $n$ is even, and $(X,-X,X,\cdots,X)$ is $n$ is odd. Clearly $Z_n$ is tight and any of its component converges in distribution to $X$. Yet $Z_n$ does not converge in distribution to $(X,\cdots,X)$.

Thank you. Do you happen to know any sufficient condition under which marginal weak convergence can imply joint weak convergence? (other than what the Cramer-Wold theorem says)
